# Rails has_many :through validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, has-many-through

I'm having trouble validating a model from a has_many through association. Below are the relevant models:

**Broadcast Model**

```
class Broadcast < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :content,
                    :expires,
                    :user_ids,
                    :user_id

    has_many :users, through: :broadcast_receipts
    has_many :broadcast_receipts, dependent: :destroy

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :content, presence: true

end
```

**Broadcast Receipt Model**

```
class BroadcastReceipt < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :broadcast
    belongs_to :user

    attr_accessible :user_id, :cleared, :broadcast_id

    validates :user_id      , presence: true
    validates :broadcast_id         , presence: true
end
```

There is also an association with Users that have_many broadcasts receipts through broadcast receipts.

The problem appears to be with the following line:

```
validates :broadcast_id         , presence: true
```

Whenever I try to create a Broadcast, I get a rollback with no error messages given. However, when removing the above line, everything works as expected.

This looks like a problem with the Broadcast not being saved before the Broadcast Receipts are being created.
Is there any way I'd be able to validate the broadcast_id is set on the receipt model?

Comment: You can create a custom validator, something like: `validate :broadcast_id_exists` and check in your validation if the broadcast exists in DB.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the same issue discussed here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8828, which was solved by adding :inverse of to the has_many associations to the join model.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some problem in your code structuring. You could give this version a try.

```
class Broadcast < ActiveRecord::Base
  # I assume these are the recipients
  has_many :broadcast_receipts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :broadcast_receipts

  # I assume this is the creator
  validates :user_id, :content, presence: true
  attr_accessible :content, :expires, :user_id, :user_ids
end

class BroadcastReceipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :broadcast
  belongs_to :user

  # You should be able to validate the presence
  # of an associated model directly
  validates :user, :broadcast, presence: true

  attr_accessible :cleared
end
```

Comment: I get why this should work, but it still doesn't, it rolls back with no errors. The interesting thing is that it used to work before upgrading to Rails 3.2.11, but I can't find anything in the changelogs which would cause it to stop working. It's still trying to save the receipt before the broadcast is actually being saved, so it has no broadcast_id to pass in.